# Weird template include and extends behavior in Django

Tags: django, templates, include, extends

Gurus,
I googled so many times on this issue but I can barely find any useful information.

So assume that we have a `base.html` template as:

```
{% block test %}This is the base!{% endblock %}
```

And 2 child templates under that, `a.html` and `b.html`

a.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block test %}This is the A!{% endblock %}
```

b.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block test %}This is the B!{% endblock %}
```

Now we have 4th template as `root.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% include 'a.html' %}
        {% include 'b.html' %}
        {% include 'base.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I render the root.html, I expects to get sth like:

> This is the A! This is the B! This is the Base!

But strangely what I got is always:

> This is the A! This is the A! This is the A!

Why exactly is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I guess I found the root cause: djang debug_toolbars plugin.
Once I disable it in the settings.py then everything works just fine...

This is weird but I guess I would post the issue the plugin's issue tracking list.

Hopefully this could help whoever had the same problem

[EDIT]
This bug looks like being fixed in the latest 0.8.4 revision, and it was bugging me so much in the 0.8.3 time.